# Mutate variable in main df from conditional in nested df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

How can one create a new variable in the main dataframe using a conditional (if else) statement based on nested data in a list-column?

If we take the cars dataset:

```r
library(dplyr)

cars_nest <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()
```

And want to create a binary variable where any value of carb > 2 equals 1, otherwise 0. I tried the following but get an error.

```r
cars_nest  <- cars_nest |> 
  mutate(test = ifelse(any(cars_nest$carb) > 2, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems in your code:

1. Your `any` should include the condition (i.e. `any(... > 2)`)
2. You don't have a `cars_nest` variable to use in `mutate`, that is the name of the dataframe object, not the column (it should be `data` column)
3. You need `rowwise` for this type of operation

One suggestion:

1. Since the output of a logical comparison (`... > 2`) is already logical, you can take advantage of `as.integer` to corce it into integers without using `ifelse`

So the code should be:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cars_nest <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() 
  
cars_nest %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(test = as.integer(any(data$carb > 2)))
  # or mutate(test = ifelse(any(data$carb > 2), 1, 0))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise:  cyl
    cyl data                test
  <dbl> <list>             <dbl>
1     6 <tibble [7 × 10]>      1
2     4 <tibble [11 × 10]>     0
3     8 <tibble [14 × 10]>     1
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't understand why rowwise() is needed for this though.

Comment: @LucaS Because in this case you are figuring out some values in a nested dataframe per `cyl` (row)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to `map` the logic from the nested frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cars_nest <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()

cars_nest |> 
  mutate(test = map_dbl(data, \(x) `+`(any(x$carb >2))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl data                test
#>   <dbl> <list>             <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]>      1
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>     0
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>     1
```

Or in base R:

```r
cars_nest$test <- sapply(cars_nest$data, \(x) `+`(any(x$carb >2)))
cars_nest
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl data                test
#>   <dbl> <list>             <int>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]>      1
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>     0
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>     1
```